# Groovy join two variable b with same variable a

Tags: groovy

**I have two data sets which**

x=[a,a,b,b,b], y=[1,2,3,4,5]

**I want it become by using groovy**

a = 1,2
b = 3,4,5

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are possibly shorter ways, but here is one way:

```
def x = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
def y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def first = { p, q -> p }
def second = { r, s -> s }
[x, y].transpose().groupBy(first).collectEntries{ k, v -> [k, v.collect(second)] }
// => [a:[1, 2], b:[3, 4, 5]]
```